# objects 1:1 relation with "Pass by reference"

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have two classes `User` and `Task`:

```
public class User {

private Task task;
private List<Item> items;

// constructor
public User() {
    this.task = new Task(this);
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
}

// getters

}
```

the Task class has a reference to User:

```
public class Task{

// should be always the same as user.items !!!
private List<Item> items;
private User user;

// constructor
public Task(User user){
    this.user = user;
    // Pass by reference ?
    this.items = user.getItems();
}

public void addItem(Item item){
    this.items.add(item);
}

}
```

Now my questions:

1. If I add an `item` with `task.addItem(item)` will this item also be added to `user.items`? Is the lifecycle and the instance of `user.items` exactly and always the same as `task.items`.
2. Actually I have a lot of methods within `User.class` and want to extract that methods within `Task.class`. With this, I have a 1:1 relationship between user and task. Is there any other design pattern for that (composition/aggregation).

Comment: `User.items` and `Task.items` are two completely different variables. `Task.items` has a reference to `User.Items`?, uses as an abbreviation, so they should not be different variables, because of "Pass by reference" within the no args constructors.

Comment: So then: @JoakimDanielson you say it is a *poor design*. My **question 2** asks for a better design for this use case (You see, I want to split one big class into two). Any recommendation?

Comment: There is a difference between aggregation and composition. @JoakimDanielson You recommend composition (one object cannot exist without the other object). But I want to use aggregation (one object can exist without the other object). I need to use aggregation because of the existing domain logic.

Comment: Yes, and **question 1** still exist, but with my source code it is obvious that I pass the items **by reference** so the `items` and all its manipulations are consistent and still the same (it does not matter in which object the `items` is used).